# Drupal - make the cancel link on the confirm page a button

Tags: php, drupal, confirm

When I press the delete button on some content, I'm taken to a confirmation page. The delete option is a button, while the cancel option is a link. That looks pretty weird. I found that there's a form_confirm() function in drupal, but I can't understand how to use it. Does anyone know how to make the cancel link into a button?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or this using no javascript (and replacing eregi() with preg_match()...

```
  if ( $form['#theme'] == 'confirm_form' ) {
    $no = $form['actions']['cancel']['#value'];
    if (!is_null($no)) {
      // Get the text to put on the cancel button
      $value = preg_replace('/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e', '', $no);
      preg_match('/href\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"/', $no, $href);
      $form['actions']['cancel']['#value'] = '';
      $form['href']=array(
        '#type'=>'value',
        '#value'=>$href[1],
      );

      // Add our own button
      $form['actions']['docancel'] = array(
        '#type' => 'submit',
        '#name' => 'cancel',
        '#submit' => array('mymodule_confirm_form_cancel'),
        '#value' => $value,
      );

    }
  }
```

and

```
function mymodule_confirm_form_cancel(&$form,&$form_state) {
  $href=$form['href']['#value'];
  if ( !is_null($href) ) {
    $form['#redirect']=$href;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The reason the cancel link looks like a link, is because it is a link `<a>`, while the confirm button, is a form submit element `<input type="submut>`.

If you want to make the cancel link, to look like a submit button, you can do that with pure CSS.

Comment: In Safari (and Chrome?), it's as easy as using `-webkit-appearance: push-button`.

Comment: I've been looking around on the internet but can't find the proper css code. All I find is how to make stylish buttons, but I simply want a regular system button.

Answer (score 1):

Using hook_form_alter() , try this :

```
if($form['#theme'] == 'confirm_form') {
    $no = $form['actions']['cancel']['#value'];
    if (!is_null($no)) {
      // Get the text to put on the cancel button
      $value = preg_replace('/(<\/?)(\w+)([^>]*>)/e', '', $no);
      eregi('m|href\s*=\s*\"([^\"]+)\"|ig', $no, $href);

      $form['actions']['cancel']['#value'] = '';

      // Add our own button
      $form['actions']['docancel'] = array(
        '#type' => 'button',
        '#button_type' => 'reset',
        '#name' => 'cancel',
        '#submit' => 'false',
        '#value' => $value,
        '#attributes' => array(
          'onclick' => '$(this).parents("form").attr("allowSubmission", "false");window.location = "'.$href[1].'";',
        ),
      );
      // Prevent the form submission via our button
      $form['#attributes']['onsubmit'] = 'if ($(this).attr("allowSubmission") == "false") return false;';
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

For Drupal 7 I use:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_form_alter().
 */
function yourmodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
  // Change 'cancel' link to 'cancel' button. 
  if ( $form['#theme'] == 'confirm_form' ) {
    if ($form['actions']['cancel']['#type'] == 'link') {
      $title = $form['actions']['cancel']['#title'];
      $href = $form['actions']['cancel']['#href'];
      if (!is_null($title) and !is_null($href)) {
        // Disable Cancel link.
        $form['actions']['cancel']['#title'] = '';
        // Add our own Cancel button.
        $form['actions']['docancel'] = array(
          '#type' => 'submit',
          '#name' => 'cancel',
          '#submit' => array('yourmodule_confirm_form_cancel'),
          '#value' => $title,
        );
      }
    }
  }
}

/**
 * Redirect to previous page after confirm form cancel().
 */
function yourmodule_confirm_form_cancel(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $href = $form['actions']['cancel']['#href'];
  if (!is_null($href)) {
    $form_state['redirect'] = $href;
  }
}
```

Issue also has been reported for Drupal 8, but Drupal core team has no intention to solve the issue in core. See Drupal support request [Change confirmation form Cancel link to a button](https://www.drupal.org/node/991774).

Best regards,
Baso.